# "...averted crash" vs. "...avoided crash"

Tags: differences, synonyms, word-usage, equivalence

In the usage given below, "avert" and "avoid" appear to mean the same thing:

> ...**averted** crash
>   ...**avoided** crash

The words "avert" and "avoid" are different and have their respective meanings. But, going by the given usage, their meanings appear to overlap to an extent.

The research (http://goenglishforever.blogspot.in/2010/02/difference-between-avert-and-avoid.html) does not give a clear picture.

What is correct scope of their respective meanings? Where do they overlap? Where do they differ?

Comment: One way in which they are similar is that both of them would usually employ an article (i.e., [_averted **a** crash, avoided **a** crash_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=averted+crash%2Caverted+a+crash%2Cavoided+crash%2Cavoided+a+crash&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)).

Answer (score 1):

From dictionary.reference.com:

> **[avert](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/avert?s=t)**:
>
> 1. to turn away or aside
> 2. to ward off; prevent

and

> **[avoid](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/avoid?s=t)**:
>
> 1. to keep away from; keep clear of; shun
> 2. to prevent from happening
> 3. *Law.* to make void or of no effect; invalidate.

Clearly definition 2 for both is "to prevent", and in this sense they completely overlap and are synonymous.

However, **avoid** has an additional meaning which is relevant in some cases: *to keep clear of*. In my experience (vaguely supported by [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avoid%20a%20car%20accident%2Cavert%20a%20car%20accident%2Cavoid%20a%20disaster%2Cavert%20a%20disaster&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavoid%20a%20car%20accident%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavoid%20a%20disaster%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavert%20a%20disaster%3B%2Cc0), but not, unfortunately, conclusively) it is more common to use **avoid** where there is *physical avoidance* involved.

Hence for preventing two cars hitting each other, I would be more likely to use **avoid**:

> I avoided a car accident

whereas for preventing Armageddon I would be more likely to use **avert**:

> I averted the disaster

But, as said previously, they are synonyms and hence either **avoid** or **avert** would be valid in either of my examples.

Comment: I've heard *"averted a car accident"*, and *"avoided a car accident"* as well.

Comment: @NVZ - Agreed, but I believe "avoided" is more common for a car accident, as backed up by the ngram. I've made a minor revision to state that either is acceptable, I just have a personal preference.